# Spring @DependsOn annotation on @Configuration class

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

Tried to create a configuration class which depends on another bean class using `@DependsOn` annotation and later found that `@DependsOn` only work along with `@Bean` and `@Component` and **not** with `@Configuration`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    private static final String URL_MAPPINGS = "/*";
    private static final Class<?>[] classes = new Class[]{Application.class, Config1.class};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(classes, args);
    }
    
    ...
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {
    @Value("${db.name}")
    private String dbName;
    
    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String url;
 
    @Override
    public MongoClient mongo() {
        ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString("mongodb:"+url);
        MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
            .build();
        
        return MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongo(), dbName);
    }

}
```

```
@Import({ MongoConfig.class, Config2.class})
@Configuration
public class Config1 {
 public BeanA beanA(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate, Environment environment) {
   return new BeanA(mongoTemplate);
 }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.test")
//this should be processed after BeanA is created, similar to @DependsOn
public class Config2 {
   ...
}
```

```
public class BeanA {
 private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

 public BeanA(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate, Environment environment) {
   this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
   this.applicationPropertySource = new ApplicationPropertySource(SOURCE_NAME);
   MutablePropertySources mutablePropertySources = ((StandardEnvironment) environment).getPropertySources();
   mutablePropertySources.addFirst(applicationPropertySource);
   getExistingProperties().forEach((key, val) -> applicationPropertySource.set(key, val));
 }

 private Map<String, String> getExistingProperties() {
   //assume values are obtained from DB
 }

 public static class ApplicationPropertySource extends PropertiesPropertySource {
    public ApplicationPropertySource(String name) {
        super(name, new HashMap());
    }

    public Object set(String key, String value) {
        return getSource().put(key, value);
    }
}
```

I like to achieve this to avoid adding `@DependsOn` annotation on all the beans in the project, is this even possible?

Spring version is v1.5.12.RELEASE

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why *exactly* do you want `Config2` "processed" after the creation of the other bean?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- beanA has some custom logic to update the application variables, and that should happen before the variables are assigned to beans.

Comment: Then "beanA" should probably be one of the Spring initializer classes and declared as a static method.

Comment: beanA is depends on MongoTemplate to access MongoDB, i'll update the question with these details. thanks!!

Comment: adding below line in META-INFA/spring.factories file is working if EnvironmentVariablesApplicationContextInitializer.java is not depending on MongoDB.
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer=com.test.EnvironmentVariablesApplicationContextInitializer